# how to validate that variable is Array of objects defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have javascript class Connection and I have variable that should contain array of Connection object.

How to validate the variable?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: Please post some code containing an example of what you are trying to achieve, and explain how you want to validate the variable. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[your array of Connection].every(elem => elem instanceof Connection);
```

It returns true if all items in your array are Connections, false otherwise

Function that checks your need

```
function isAllConnections(array) {
   return array.every(function(elem) {
       return elem instanceof Connection;
   });
}
```

Comment: @P.K. It's ES6 code, I just update code for ES5, try it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the variable exists and contains values:

```
var myArrayOfConnections = [];
if(myArrayOfConnections && myArrayOfConnections.length) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The first check will evaluate whether it exists, second will check the length is greater than 0

Comment: but how to validate that each element is Connection object?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to make sure the variable is Array:

1. `Array.isArray( x );`
2. `function isArray(x) { return x.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1;}`
3. `x instanceof Array`

Then you can check each element in the array:

```
for(var i in x) { if( x[i].isPrototypeOf(Connection) ) }
```

Comment: `connectionArray[c].isPrototypeOf(Connection)` gives me false with proper data

Answer (score -1):

You might use instanceof. Without elaboration, your question is a bit unclear, but this may be useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Finstanceof